# how to make 10 copies of initial file, if first file is as-1.txt second should be as-2.txt and so on

Tags: c++, oop

Loop isn't making 10 copies and i have no idea how to change file names

```
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;
void main()
{
        char str[200];   
        ifstream  myfile("as-1.txt");

        if (!myfile)
        {
            cerr << "file not opening";
            exit(1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            ofstream myfile2("as-2.txt");
            while (!myfile.eof())
            {
                myfile.getline(str, 200);
                myfile2 << str << endl;
            }
        }
       system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Your `ofstream` file name is hard-coded to be `as-2.txt` - it never changes.  You need to use `i` to create a new file name each time through the loop.

Comment: Please try to make your questions more than one line long! We would love much more information to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution using plain `C` API from `<cstdio>`. Easily customizable.

```
const char* file_name_format = "as-%d.txt"; //Change that if you need different name pattern
const char* original_file_name = "as-1.txt"; //Original file
const size_t max_file_name = 255;

FILE* original_file = fopen(original_file_name, "r+");

if(!original_file)
    //file not found, handle error

fseek(original_file, 0, SEEK_END); //(*)
long file_size = ftell(original_file);
fseek(original_file, 0, SEEK_SET);

char* original_content = (char*)malloc(file_size);
fread(original_content, file_size, 1, original_file);

fclose(original_file);

size_t copies_num = 10;
size_t first_copy_number = 2;
char file_name[max_file_name];

for(size_t n = first_copy_number; n < first_copy_number + copies_num; ++n)
{
    snprintf(file_name, max_file_name, file_name_format, n);
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "w");
    fwrite(original_content, file_size, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
}

free(original_content);
```

---

**(*)** As noted [on this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/), `SEEK_END` may not necessarily be supported (i.e. it is not a portable solution). However most POSIX-compliant systems (including the most popular Linux distros), Windows family and OSX support this without any problems.

Oh, and one more thing. This line

```
while (!myfile.eof())
```

is not quite correct. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) - it explains why you shouldn't write such code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    const int copies_of_file = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= copies_of_file; ++i)
    {
       std::ostringstream name;
       name << "filename as-" << i << ".txt";
       std::ofstream ofile(name.str().c_str());
       ofile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That will make 10 copies of a blank .txt file named "filename as-1.txt" "filename as-2.txt" etc.

Note also the use of `int main`: `main` always has a return of `int`, never `void`